# Understanding AJAX CORS and security considerations

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, cors

I am trying to understand why CORS is working in way that it works.

As I learned from [this post](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/), when page from **www.a.com** makes AJAX request to **www.b.com**, then it's the **www.b.com** that decides if request should be allowed or not.

But what is exactly secured on client in such model?
For example, if a hacker succeeds to make an XSS script injection to my page, then it makes an AJAX request to his domain to store user data. So a hacker's domain will allow such a request for sure.

I thought that **www.a.com** should decide to which domains to allow the request to. So in theory within a header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** I would like to put the whole list of the domains that are allowed for AJAX CORS requests.

Can someone explain what security problems the current CORS implementation handles?

Comment: yes, that's right, the domain that is serving data ( the saas ) can list it's 'allowed' domains. (ACAO's) After that it is the responsibility of the SaaS to ensure that requests are made safe ( through regular 'web server' means - string sanitisation, catch DSA's etc )

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> As I learned from this post, when page from `www.a.com` makes AJAX request to `www.b.com`, then it's the `www.b.com` that decides if request should be allowed or not.

Not quite. The request isn't blocked (at least, if it is [simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests)).

By default the JavaScript running on `www.a.com` is forbidden access to the response from `www.b.com`.

CORS provides a means by which  `www.b.com` can give permission to the JavaScript on `www.a.com` to access the response.

> But what is exactly secured on client in such model?

It stops the author of `www.a.com` from reading data from `www.b.com` using the browser of a User who has visited both sites and has been authenticated on `www.b.com` (and thus has access to data that isn't public).

For example, Alice is logged into Google. Alice visits `malicious.example` which uses XMLHttpRequest to access data from `gmail.com`. Alice has a GMail account so the response has a list of the most recent email in her inbox. The same origin policy prevents `malicious.example` from reading it.

> For example, hacker success to make XSS script injection to my page, then it makes AJAX request to his domain to store user data. So hackers domain will allow such request for sure.

Correct. XSS is a different security problem that needs to be addressed at source (i.e. at `www.a.com` and not in the browser).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [@Quentin's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21854745/413180), there is another technology known as [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) which describes what you are after.

> I thought that www.a.com should decide to which domains to allow the request to. So in theory within a header Access-Control-Allow-Origin I would like to put the whole list of the domains that are allowed for AJAX CORS requests.

With CSP, you could set a header from your domain (`www.a.com` in your example) to restrict AJAX requests:

> connect-src limits the origins to which you can connect (via XHR, WebSockets, and EventSource).

So to use this you can add this `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP header to your HTML response:

```
Content-Security-Policy: connect-src 'self'
```

This will restrict AJAX requests to `www.a.com` if that header is in the response from `www.a.com`:

> 'self' matches the current origin, but not its subdomains

[See here](http://caniuse.com/contentsecuritypolicy) for supported browsers.