# Angularjs - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angularjs, cors

trying to access an api with angularjs:

eg.

```
 footballdataAPI.getTeams = function() {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = '613a6b6937394ae8a94d69f358f76902';
        return $http.get('http://www.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/398/leagueTable?callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
    };
```

But I get the console error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/398/leagueTable?callback=JSON_CALLBACK. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://alexanderlloyd.info' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Do they need to allow requests from my domain on their side? Or is there something I can add to make this work ad they have already given me an authorisation token as shown in the code.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource- AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134117/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-an)

Answer (score 2):

The server must send the `Access-Controll-Allow-Origin` header, telling the browser that requests from your application's host are allowed - otherwise the browser refuses to make such request (as a built-in security measure).

If interested, you can read a much more detailed explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: so where the api is hosted is where access-control-allow-origin needs to be sent? Right?

Comment: Yes, the API server needs to be configured to send this header.

Comment: That is, the server must know how to respond to http OPTIONS requests and respond with appropriate headers.