# Setting up Instagram Authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, instagram

I'm having trouble setting up authentication with Instagram. My goal is to acquire an access token to post comments to a user's account.

I seem to be having a CORS issues because I keep getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID…direct_uri=http://localhost:1337/api/instagram/redirect&response_type=code.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1337' is therefore not allowed
access.
```

I'm utilizing [Instagram's Authentication Documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

My understanding of CORS issues is pretty deficient. I'm kind of just throwing things at it without really understanding what it's doing.

Here's my HTML:

```
<form ng-controller="InstagramController" name="instagramForm" ng-submit="authenticate()">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Authenticate Instagram</button>
</form>
```

The Angular Controller:

```
app.controller('InstagramController', function($scope, instagramFactory){

  $scope.authenticate = function(){ 

    instagramFactory.authenticate()
    .then(function(res){
      console.log("res", res);
    });   

  };

});
```

The Angular Factory making the call:

```
app.factory('instagramFactory', function($http){

    return {
        authenticate: function() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1337/api/instagram/redirect&response_type=code'
            });
        }
    };

});
```

And the route where I'm receiving the redirect from Instagram (which I'm never reaching) once the user has chosen to give my app access to their account. :

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var cors = require('cors');
module.exports = router;
router.use(cors());
...
router.get('/redirect', function(req, res, next){

    console.log("req.query.code", req.query.code);
    res.end();

});
```

When I type the http request directly into my browser, I am getting to the backend and receiving the 'code' necessary to request an access token.

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1337/api/instagram/redirect&response_type=code

I suspect that I need to do modify the headers in my Angular Factory in order to properly issue that HTTP request, but I'm not sure how to do that.

In my app.config function, I tried some $httpProvider methods that I found in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134117/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-an), but there doesn't seem to be any difference.

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, ezfbProvider, $httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
...
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You solve this? I had the same issue.