# How can we add security in ajax get request in laravel 5?

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I need to add security for ajax get method in Laravel 5. For POST, PUT and DELETE Laravel token is good. But How can I add security in ajax get request.

**Security**

If an hacker try to access an ajax page directly form another domain. I need to check the domain name and restrict.

I have added middleware but I am not sure Is this the correct way?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AjaxMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ((!$request->ajax()) || ($request->url() != url()->current())){
            return response('Forbidden.', 403);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) suppose to block? Check this out: [Understanding AJAX CORS and security considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854516/understanding-ajax-cors-and-security-considerations)

You don't have to put any extra layer of protection if you are afraid that someone from a different website might do ajax calls to your website. They will be blocked by browser, by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same CSFR technique for the GET requests, to verify the request comes from a valid session.