# Detect browser tab close without jquery and send some data to php file

Tags: javascript

I have wrote a script that send some data to an external php file without jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var statsPage = 'http://www.my-url.com/response.php';

function ca(c,o,n,t,e,t,u){return p={type:c,userid:o,gender:n}}

ca("pageview", "1", "male");


var params = Object.keys(p).map(function(k) {
    return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(p[k])
}).join('&')

const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
//req.addEventListener('load' /*callback after req is complete*/);
req.open('GET', statsPage + '?' + params);
req.send();

req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert(req.responseText);
    }
}
</script>
```

What i also want to do is to send data when the browser tab is closed, so i wrote a script like below but it is not working. I don't get a response from the php file here.

```
navigator.sendBeacon = navigator.sendBeacon || function () {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.my-url.com/response.php?pag_title=1');
    xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
};
```

I found also this script but it gives me also no response from the response.php file as an alert:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function()  {  
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.my-url.com/response.php?pag_titel=1', true);

// If specified, responseType must be empty string or "text"
xhr.responseType = 'test';

xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            //console.log(xhr.response);
            //console.log(xhr.responseText);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
};

xhr.send(null); 

    }
```

**EDIT**

I did also the following test but now it gives me an alertbox with the value 1 first and then an alert with the response of the function ca (see first part of the code on top for the function). So i think the onbeforeunload is not working here. If i close browser tab i get nothing in response.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function()  {  
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.digital-productions.be/dev/analytics/response.php?pag_titel=1', true);

// If specified, responseType must be empty string or "text"
xhr.responseType = 'test';

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}

xhr.send(null); 

    }
```

Comment: "it is not working" is not a problem description. What actually happens? Does the handler function get called? Does it run to completion without an exception? Does a network request get sent?

Comment: I don't get any reponse as an alert from my external php file here. I have edited my question.

Comment: OK, and what are the answers to my other questions?

Comment: I have an second EDIT on my post with some new code i tried to implement. The request there is send, otherwise i don't get a response. But the onbeforeunload is not working there.

Comment: @melpomene: Can you help me with my question?

Comment: Anyone else who can help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the beforeunload event to execute code before the user leaves the page, or you could warn them that there is unsaved changes. You can return a message by using `e.returnValue = "Message";`.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
    //code        
});
```

Here is a link from the mozilla documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Comment: Do i need jquery for that? I don't want to use it. I don't want to send a message but want to start a XMLHttpRequest and send some data to the reponse.php when a browser tab is closed

Comment: Can you help me with my edited post? I have wrote a new script for the beforeunload but it fires the event also at the beginning if i do a refresh and not in the beforeunload. Your addEventListener is not working. I get no response.

Comment: You don't need jquery

Comment: Javascript expects you to give a return value. Just put any string in there, and you code should run. Here is a fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/sw9s4337/)

Comment: the return must be a xmlhttprequest here. And what about the sendbeacon option? I don't know how to implement. Can you help me out here?