# XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.worldidverification.com/ Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I am implementing World id document verification...

When i am running code on server there is error message as below :

VM1268:2 XMLHttpRequest cannot load Url Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     async: false,
     url: "https://api.worldidverification.com/WIDVService.svc/json/WIDV_DocumentVerification",
     data: JSON.stringify(DocumentVerificationSearchRequestModel),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) { 
         if (data.Status == "false") {
             alert(data.response);
         }
         else {
             $("#tblData").show();
             var trHTML = '';
             var result = data.documentVerificationResponse;
             for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                 trHTML += '<tr><td>' + result[i].searchdisplayname + '</td><td>' + result[i].matchindicator + '</td></tr>';
             }
             $('#tblDatatbody').empty().append(trHTML);
         }
     },
     error: function () {
     } });
```

Please let me know how can i resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the error message? "_No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource._"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854516/understanding-ajax-cors-and-security-considerations

Comment: Why are you trying to post to an external server from `localhost`? _"The response had HTTP status code 500"_ What is logged at `stdout` at `terminal`?

Comment: No header is not present..

Comment: Let me know how can i add header to it... i am new programmer