# Request has data but axios not reading

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, axios

i am doing a GET request using axios on laravel api request is going sucessfull 
but i am getting empty response
here is the code when i change the base url of axio

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.ajaxHeaders = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = window.ajaxHeaders
window.axios.defaults.baseURL="https://roqstaraudio.com/";
```

this is request
[image]

this is empty response
[image]
and when hitting the same url on browser getting data
[image]

and this the url i am calling from ajax by GET Request

```
https://roqstaraudio.com/api/item/list?categories[0]=2&order[0]=latest&per_page=18&relations[0]=creator
```

getting this in console 
[image]

Comment: That API is not CORS enabled....is it your own or third party?

Comment: it is third party

Comment: can access that data

Comment: Sure...when you go to that site directly but that has nothing to do with how CORS  works with cross domain requests from browser. If you don't know what OPTIONS request is like the one in image above  should read up on that too

Comment: console is updated

Comment: Well those error messages are pretty clear and easy to follow. And a simple search on those errors would have turned up a huge number of results

Answer (score 0):

That was an `OPTIONS` request, not a `GET` one. Check your console for more info

Comment: so for option request i should get the data why i am not getting response

Comment: Check your console and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854516/understanding-ajax-cors-and-security-considerations

Comment: i console i what i need to check and what i need to correct

Comment: and when my baseurl is localhost:8000 the it is working fine