# Use data of a json in javascript with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

[image: Errors]

I have a problem with using data of a json file in my html document.

At the top you can see the errors that i get.

I have this file created as a json file New.json :

```
[
    { "firstname":"Thomas", "lastname":"Anderson" },
    { "firstname":"Agent", "lastname":"Smith" },
    { "firstname":"Agent", "lastname":"Brown" }
]
```

I tried this code to get the data from my json file

```
    <script type="application/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("div").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: './New.json',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data){
                            window.alert(data);
                        },
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Show us your error message value!

Comment: Your json file is invalid. Instead of surrounding the list of elements with `{}` which produces an invalid object, use `[]` to make a valid array.

Comment: Thanks james  fixed it, but it still does not work i edited my question now there is a screenshot of the error i become

Comment: Your Json file format not valid

Comment: Really ? I changed it like James said, I use now [ ] instead of {} is it still wrong ?.

Comment: this is a CORS policy problem, you will find a ton of similar resolution here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding AJAX CORS and security considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854516/understanding-ajax-cors-and-security-considerations)

Answer (score 0):

You URL might need to be: url: './New.json',

Comment: I changed it but it still does not work.